# Artifactory upgrade from 6.14.1 to 7.10.2: migrate.sh fails to find old Artifactory version

Tags: artifactory

When running the migrate.sh script, I get this error:
File [$JFROG_HOME/artifactory/var/etc/artifactory/artifactory.properties] not found to get current version.

But the artifactory.properties file is there and in that file I can find artifactory.version=6.14.1
Does anyone know what is wrong here?

Comment: Is the $JFROG_HOME environment variable set and pointing to the correct location? what is the Art installation type and what are the steps taken to migrate? share me the wiki being referred here

Answer (score 1):

Solved it, the issue was the user that is executing migrate.sh did not get the environment variables.
Adding these lines to the .bashrc file and rebooting solved the problem:

```
export ARTIFACTORY_HOME=/var/artifactory/artifactory-home
export JFROG_HOME=/var/jfrog
export JF_PRODUCT_HOME=/var/jfrog/artifactory
```